# SQL select query to find count from given table

Tags: php, sql

I have one table in database -> applicants_detail which has two column 
 
applied_personid and applied_courseid. 
College provides number of courses. 
I have the given id to applied_courseid, that is written like this: 
arts--1
   science--2
  maths--3...
And applied_personid which contains applied person id. 
I need to count how many people applied for the course, like in the page it should show: 
 maths------15 people_applied 
science------20 people_applied
 
I tried this query:

```
$query="select * from people where people_id in(select applied_personid from applicants where applied_courseid  =".$_GET['postcourseid']." )";
```

And the code to find count     is not able to show count in the table.

```
<?php
            $count=0;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {

                    echo '<tr> <td width="10%">'.$count.'
                            <td width="50%">'.$row['student_fnm'].'
                                                            <td width="50%">'.$row['applied_courseid'].'
                            <td width="30%"><a href="'.$row['course_name'].'">course name</a>
                            ';
                        $count++;
                }


            ?>
```

Comment: please provide the table structure where mapping between course id and names are stored

Comment: The `mysql_` extension is deprecated an will be removed in the next php versions. You should use [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or work with [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s. See [Deprecated features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) in PHP 5.5x

Comment: @Florent this is the table structure the other two table, postcourse contains column course_id ,course_title  and other table people contains column student_id student_fnm

Answer (score 2):

You just need to group by `applied_courseid`. This should do it.

```
    select applied_courseid, count(applied_personid) as `count`
    from
    applicants_detail
    group by applied_courseid
```

Then if needed use the results here to join to the other tables
which you probably have (that would give the you course name e.g.).

Comment: i tried following  query i got the result as want it show like this maths------15 people_applied
science------20 people_applied                                `select postcourse.course_title,applied_courseid, count(applied_personid) as `count2` from   applicants LEFT JOIN postcourse ON applicants.applied_courseid=postcourse.course_id group by applied_courseid`  but it is possible to use where clause in above query like  `where course_owner_name='".$_SESSION['unm']."'`

Comment: i musing where clause in above query but it does not return any data `where course_owner_name='".$_SESSION['unm']."'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all data:

```
    SELECT course_name, applied_courseid as course_id, count(applied_personid) as `student_number`
    FROM applicants_detail 
    INNER JOIN course_detail ON course_detail.course_id = applicants_detail.course_id
    GROUP BY applied_courseid
```